# Cant access server media files in django + angular project

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, media

Because I wanted to do my routing in angular side I have added this url in my urls.py:

```
url(r'^.*$', Home.as_view(), name='home'),
```

in which my home view I just specify my base.html:

```
class Home(TemplateView):
    template_name = "base.html"
```

So that I can specify my `<ng-view></ng-view>` in `base.html`

Now my issues the requests to get pictures in server side like `localhost:8000/media/uploaded_pic.png`
are going to the defined url for Home.

How can I overcome this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set static and media urls in your settings file so your server knows to handle them differently:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Your catch all route for your app template needs to always come last, so to make this work during development, you need to make sure to insert your media url patterns before the final catch all that serves the template.

```
urlpatterns = static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + [ url(r'^.*$', Home.as_view(), name='home'),]
```

More: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

my personal take: I consider my API layer and my client layer as wholly seperate entities always.  My client is just a consumer of my API, so I serve my client app completely separately from my API.

Comment: I have both urls specified in my settings.py
`MEDIA_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'media') + os.sep
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' and STATIC_URL = '/static/''`

Comment: did you read the part labeled "serving static files during development"?

Comment: honestly it sounds like you're mixing concepts, a logo is static. It's an image you add and is just a static asset.  Media is used for things that are dynamic, like uploaded or dynamic content, think media content that is changed THROUGH the app. Your logo should be in your '/static/' path like '/static/assets/logo.png'

Comment: Logo is just an example I put there. Yes I have read everything and Im familiar with those settings. The issue is the url to specify base.html of my page is before the Media urls, therefore the Home url takes priority and nothing gets served

Comment: `urlpatterns = [ url(r'^.*$', Home.as_view(), name='home'),]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Comment: you're not listening.  Your logo and any other development media assets should be in your static route and your media route shouldn't come into play here.  Your static route is always matched before ANY defined URL. Media route is reserved for user uploaded content. If you change it's location to use the static route, this will work fine, or you can try to fight your framework for no reason.

Comment: Lol my friend thats exactly my issue, im trying to load uploaded media content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157935/discussion-between-beckas-and-bryan60).

Comment: then why would you use a logo as an example? Anyway, just change the order of your list so the media route comes first   
urlpatterns = static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + [ url(r'^.*$', Home.as_view(), name='home'),]

Comment: Ohhh man, how could I not see that. Thank you, sorry for the misinterpretation.